# Mongoexport troubleshooting

Tags: mongodb, command

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to save a query result to a json file however keep getting this error:

```
query '[102 105 110 100 40 123 32 36 97 110 100 58 91 32 123 100 105 115 112 108 97 121 78 97 109 101 58 47 94 65 47 105 125 44 32 123 100 105 115 112 108 97 121 78 97 109 101 58 47 101 115 36 47 125 32 44 123 102 114 105 101 110 100 115 67 111 117 110 116 58 123 36 108 116 58 50 53 125 125 93 32 125 44 123 100 105 115 112 108 97 121 78 97 109 101 58 49 44 102 111 108 108 111 119 101 114 115 67 111 117 110 116 58 49 44 102 114 105 101 110 100 115 67 111 117 110 116 58 49 125 41 46 115 111 114 116 40 123 100 105 115 112 108 97 121 78 97 109 101 58 45 49 125 41]' is not valid JSON: invalid character 'i' in literal false (expecting 'a') try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

The code I am using is

```
mongoexport --db cw2 --collection cl --query="find({ $and:[ {displayName:/^A/i}, {displayName:/es$/} ,{friendsCount:{$lt:25}}] },{"displayName":1,"followersCount":1,"friendsCount":1}).sort({"displayName":-1})" --out=data/cw2q2.json
```

Can anyone see what the issue is? I am not sure i understand what the actual message is saying.

Comment: The documented example shows the --query  keyword doesnt include a "find"  at the start. just the query.

see: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/#export-query-results

Comment: Depending on the shell you are using when launching `mongoexport`, you may need to protect the `--query` string with single quotes (`'`) rather than double quotes (`"`) to avoid the shell interpreting `$` as starting a shell variable.